# Why does this Excel 2007 VBA program fail to iterate/reassign a Range variable?

Tags: vba, excel, range

Chopped down from uber-detail history mode per suggestion.

My level of expertise: Hacked some fairly complex dialog-boxing multi-workbook macro systems ten years ago, experienced but not formally trained and rusty.

The complicated stuff in this macro works; its central bug is that it won't change that CurrentClientAnchor Range variable, the most basic operation in Excel VBA, no matter what I do. It loops as many times as you like anchored on cell A2, correctly finding the cell that should next become CurrentClientAnchor (on the real data, A4, two cells down), and creating the invoice sheet perfectly from the selected data as long as you give it permission to overwrite the copy it just created a second ago. I won't be surprised if my special last record routine breaks something, but manually stepping through, none of that If clause ever runs. The program correctly steps over it. WhatsMyAnchor should be 4 just before the last Loop command, but never changes from 2.

The only method I know for accomplishing what I want that doesn't have a commented fossil  left in the code is the first one I wrote, assigning a ClientsRange as Range over Range("A2", Cells(LastRow,1)) and then putting everything in a For...Next loop. That version also just ran over and over on the first record.

In what way am I being incredibly stupid, please?

```
Option Explicit
Sub FillOutInvoices()

Dim BilledDate As String
Dim ServiceYear As String
Dim ServiceMonth As String
Dim CompBasePath As String

Dim InvoiceTemplatePath As String
InvoiceTemplatePath = "H:\Comp\Comp Invoice BLANK PRINT COPY.xls"





'The info to change for each invoicing
'========================
'========================
CompBasePath = "H:\Comp\2014 Invoices\"
ServiceYear = "2014"
ServiceMonth = "September"
BilledDate = "02/01/2015"
'========================
'========================





Dim InvoiceFolder As String
InvoiceFolder = CompBasePath & ServiceYear & " " & ServiceMonth & " generated invoices" & "\"
If Dir(InvoiceFolder, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
  MkDir InvoiceFolder
End If
'Find the last used row on the sheet with a web recipe to speed things up
'and avoid arbitrary search windows.
Dim LastRow As Long
LastRow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'We assume our first client is in A2
Dim CurrentClientAnchor As Range
Set CurrentClientAnchor = Range("A2")
Dim DataHeight As Single
Dim NoMoreRecords As Boolean
NoMoreRecords = False

'Debugging variable so I don't have to paw through 
'a zillion properties of CCA in the Watch pane all the time
Dim WhatsMyAnchor As Single
WhatsMyAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Row

Do Until NoMoreRecords = True 'Loop captures falling through the last record, internal exit catches
  'the next result each time

  'Surprisingly the main loop. For each client, find the next one or end of job,
  'use that as an upper and lower bound to create and write the invoice

  'Transplanted inline from what should be a sub, because I need it to Just Work Now.
  'As a sub, causes Object Required error on passing the range which is a range into the range slot that's designated as a range.
  'This should become some clever run-once array of nonempty ranges someday

  'Find next nonempty A. If none before lastrow, last record; find last nonempty F, set rows, copy data, terminate macro.
  'If found, set rows and copy data
  DataHeight = 1
  Do Until CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight, 0).Value <> ""
    'Find the next nonempty cell below CurrentClientAnchor and record the offset
    'We're falling off the bottom of the last one, have to do our special last search up front here.
    If CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight, 0).Row = LastRow Then 'special finder for last record down F to first empty cell
      NoMoreRecords = True
      DataHeight = 1
      Do Until CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight, 5).Value = ""
          DataHeight = DataHeight + 1
      Loop
      Exit Do
    End If
    DataHeight = DataHeight + 1
  Loop

  'We now have our DataHeight value for the grunt work.
  'Subtract one from it, to convert to the cell offsets we'll use
  DataHeight = DataHeight - 1

  'Inlined from sub again because I apparently don't know how to pass a variable.
  'MakeInvoiceFile
  Dim SourceBook As Workbook
  Set SourceBook = ThisWorkbook
  Dim InvoiceFileName As String
  InvoiceFileName = InvoiceFolder & _
    CurrentClientAnchor.Value & " " & ServiceYear & " " & ServiceMonth & " Invoice" & ".xls"
  Dim DestBook As Workbook
  Dim Template As Workbook
  Application.Workbooks.Open InvoiceTemplatePath
  Set Template = ActiveWorkbook
  Set DestBook = ActiveWorkbook

  DestBook.SaveAs (InvoiceFileName)

  SourceBook.Activate
  'Close for debugging cleanliness, more elegant keep open behavior later
  'Doesn't work. Maybe not even ugly, anyway cut for dev time.
  'Template.Close

  'More debugging watchable variables
  Dim WhereCopyingRow As Single
  Dim WhereCopyingColumn As Single

  Dim CopyRange As Range
  'Client name into job name
  Set CopyRange = CurrentClientAnchor
  WhereCopyingRow = CopyRange.Row
  WhereCopyingColumn = CopyRange.Column
  CopyRange.Copy
  DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(3, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  'Service address into job location
  Set CopyRange = CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(0, 3)
  WhereCopyingRow = CopyRange.Row
  WhereCopyingColumn = CopyRange.Column
  CopyRange.Copy
  DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(4, 4).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  'Billing address into billing address
  Set CopyRange = CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(0, 4)
  WhereCopyingRow = CopyRange.Row
  WhereCopyingColumn = CopyRange.Column
  CopyRange.Copy
  DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(9, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  'Billing Date into Date Billed
  'Currently discarded for progress
  'DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(24, 3).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  'Descriptions
  Set CopyRange = Range(CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(0, 5), CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight, 5))
  WhereCopyingRow = CopyRange.Row
  WhereCopyingColumn = CopyRange.Column
  CopyRange.Copy
  DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(13, 2).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  'Totals
  Set CopyRange = Range(CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(0, 14), CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight, 15))
  WhereCopyingRow = CopyRange.Row
  WhereCopyingColumn = CopyRange.Column
  CopyRange.Copy
  DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(13, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  'Overall total
  Set CopyRange = CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight, 16)
  WhereCopyingRow = CopyRange.Row
  WhereCopyingColumn = CopyRange.Column
  CopyRange.Copy
  DestBook.Sheets(1).Cells(24, 6).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues, xlPasteSpecialOperationNone
  DestBook.Save
  DestBook.Close

  'SourceBook appears to be activated when we close DestBook, but it's failing to iterate so let's make sure.
  SourceBook.Activate

  'CurrentClientAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight + 1, 0)
  'WhatsMyAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Row

  'Apparently we can't assign a range to its offset, fails to iterate, so
  'we pop out to selection and back to the variable.

  'CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight + 1, 0).Select
  'CurrentClientAnchor = Selection
  'WhatsMyAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Row

  'Nope. Escalate to activating and assigning.

  'CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight + 1, 0).Activate
  'CurrentClientAnchor = ActiveCell
  'WhatsMyAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Row

  'That doesn't iterate either, it's really hard for a programming language in
  'Excel to iterate on the most common object in Excel,
  'so let's turn the blasted stupid debugging variable into an absolute cell selector

  Set CurrentClientAnchor = ActiveSheet.Cells(WhatsMyAnchor + DataHeight + 1, 0)
  WhatsMyAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Row

  'That throws a 1004 error with or without the Set, "application or object-defined error", thanks.
  'It's just impossible to move a Range down a few cells. Excel VBA can't do that. You can't vary a Range variable.

Loop
MsgBox "All successfully written"


End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is a lot of writing for a relatively small question, I would recommend cutting out any non-essential text in future questions; a lot of people will just see the sheer volume of text and move on.

With respect to your issue I think a minor change would do the job:

The examples you have commented out should work if you just add `Set` in front of them:

`Set CurrentClientAnchor = CurrentClientAnchor.Offset(DataHeight + 1, 0)`

As you have it with the line

`Set CurrentClientAnchor = ActiveSheet.Cells(WhatsMyAnchor + DataHeight + 1, 0)`

Changed to

`Set CurrentClientAnchor = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & WhatsMyAnchor + DataHeight + 1)`

Should also work.

Comment: Thanks for the guidance, I trimmed it. Most questions I see on SO meet with "Why didn't you try X" or "What happens when Y", so I tried to forestall that but I guess I went overboard.

And indeed, thanks for the answer. Dropping "Set" was the super-simple syntax I'd overlooked on my otherwise correct methods, then subconsciously restored on my final incorrect one. The macro is now working as expected and I feel dumb but sane.